# Contains or for-loop, what's more efficient?

Tags: swift, for-loop, contains

Using Swift, I have an array of about 30 strings (each string is a single word). I also have a variable string and I want to check if the string has a matching value in the array.

My question is, from an efficiency standpoint, should I just use:

```
if myArray.contains("MyString") {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Or should I loop through it?

```
for i in 0..<myArray.count {
    if myArray[i] == "MyString" {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: `myArray.contains()` enumerates the array as well, but stops at the first occurrence of the given element.

Comment: You should ask yourself: Does it matter? Is that check a performance bottleneck for the app? If the answer is "yes" then use Instruments and measure. If the answer is "no", choose what you feel more comfortable with.

Comment: @MartinR Will do, thank you!

Comment: There is also a third way: `if myArray.index(of:"MyString") != nil`

Comment: first is more efficient as compared to second one from time complexity perspective

Comment: In most cases, implementing things like `contains(where:)`, `indexOf(where:)`, etc. yourself using for loops is faster than the closure-using standard library versions. However, this relies on you knowing your stuff to implement is properly and efficiently. It also makes your code longer, adds new susceptibility  to bugs, and makes maintenance harder. Can you squeeze out some trivial amount of better performance? Most certainly. Is it worth the hassle? Profile your app, and decide for yourself.

Comment: In this case, however, there isn't any closure overhead to deal with, so your custom implementation will almost certainly be slower. Plus, your custom implementation will make your application binary larger, and will add to ram usage and cache misses, which can further decrease performance.

Comment: If you're concerned about efficiency for testing membership in a collection, consider using a `Set` instead, whose `contain` method is much faster.

Comment: (Then again, if we're dealing with 30 strings, the performance difference is going to be negligible, either way.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From an efficiency standpoint it is more efficient to use `myArray.contains("myString")` since it will stop once it reaches value equal to "myString" , if it does exist in the array at all. A `for-loop` will continue through all the values even after it finds the value you have specified so it is less efficient but probably only offers a negligible efficiency upgrade unless the array has a significantly large number of elements.

Like @vadian said there is a 3rd way. An there is also a 4th way, using a `while-loop`, which you could make stop after the value you have searched for is found by using a `break` (and you could also do this in your `for-loop`), however using `.contains(...)` is far more readable and concise and thus in my opinion is the best choice.

Comment: You can stop a `for` loop with a `break` statement on success, too.

Answer (score 3):

If you really care about performance and you have a large dataset, the HashSet or in Swift, simply Set will give you O(1) lookup time for a contains call.  So using the better data structure will have a massive impact on performance here while the implementation detail of using a loop or the contains function will be a non-factor.

```
Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).contains(3) //O(1) 

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].contains(3) //O(log n) assuming a binary search
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the kind of thing where code readability is way more important than performance. The difference in a for-loop and a contains will be pretty much unnoticeable unless you have a really huge array you are using. In my opinion, you should go with contains.